# The Forbidden rule in htaccess using OR doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

This code correctly returns 403 error for URLs that don't end with `/` and have string name `view-ports`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !view-ports
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

I'm going to add more strings like `view-ports` into the code so I tried this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !view-ports [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !string-2 [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !string-3
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The code above is not working, it returns 403 error for all URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer, here it is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(view-ports|string-2|string-3)
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```